# Quote post not showing up in Tumblr theme. What's going on? What did I do wrong?

Tags: html, tumblr

Here's what I'm doing right now.

http://lt-colbylovesamanda.tumblr.com/

And here's the code for my quote post.

```
{block:Quote}
<div class="quote">
<blockquote>"{Quote}"</blockquote>
{block:Source}<cite>{Source}</cite>{/block:Source} ({Length})
</div>
{/block:Quote}
```

Is there anything I've done wrong? If so, how can I fix that?

Comment: Please provide us with more code and I can update my answer below with more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `" "` from `{Quote}`:

```
<blockquote>{Quote}</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few things wrong with your code.

For starters, IDs should only be used once on a page, but you've got `<article id="posts">` showing up quite a few times. What you should be doing is something like this:

```
<section id="posts">
    <article class="post">
        <!-- your post -->
    </article>

    <article class="post">
        <!-- your post -->
    </article>
</section>
```

You can then added specific post-type classnames to the `<article>` by doing this:

```
<article class="post type-{PostType}{block:Photoset}set{/block:Photoset}">
```

This will pump out things like:

```
<article class="post type-photoset">
    <!-- photoset post -->
</article>

<article class="post type-quote">
    <!-- quote post -->
</article>

<article class="post type-video">
    <!-- video post -->
</article>
```

Which will help you better target each of your post types (and let you get rid of that extra `<div>` that you have in your markup.

The reason for your quote posts not showing up probably means that there is some sort of error in your Tumblr theme's code just before that. We'd need to see the rest of the code to answer that specifically.

Comment: Actually, I had some of the post tags placed below the closing article tag. I didn't realize that. Thanks anyway. My quote post is finally showing up.